# Padding from the 5th child element + CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have `ul` with for example 15 child `li` elements. The width and height from every li is the same. There are 4 `li` elements on one row. No I would like to have the elements starting with the fifth child element to have a `padding` of `20px`. Can I do this with a css selector or do I need to use a check to add a class beginning from the fifth element?

Comment: Have you tried `ul > li:nth-child(n+5) { padding: 20px; }`?

Comment: `ul > li:nth-of-type(n+5) { padding: 20px; }`

Comment: `li:nth-child(n+5) { padding: 20px; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo-class this can be done easily:

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+5) {
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/CVuBK/2/

Comment: It should be `:nth-child(n+5)`. In the fiddle demo you have added a `<h1>` element which is the first child of its parent (the `<body>`).

Comment: As nth-child is not supported on IE. You can use the adjacent sibling selector to select from the 5th element: ul li + li + li + li + li {
    background:#ff0000;
}  /* select each element that has 4 adjacent elements */

Answer (score 3):

Use ***:nth-child()*** pseudo-class. It will affect 5th `li` elements onwards

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+5) {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/QGM5D/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
ul li:nth-child(5) {  
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: it will affect only 5th element

Comment: You should use my answer. ul li:nth-child(n+5) –  Dean Meehan 5 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Fix for Dan Meehan answer: works perfectly with good html ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/CVuBK/1/

```
<h1>
```